# can we pass non tensor to tf.py_func input?

Tags: tensorflow

```
def np_function( np_array1, float_value):
    np_array2 = ...
return np_array2 

#tensorflow customised op
def tf_function( tf_tensor_in_gpu, float_value):
return  \
    tf.py_func(np_function,[tf_tensor_in_gpu, float_value],[tf.float32])
```

I want to make a customized tensorflow op from my function, using "tf.py_func". How can I pass non-tensor input (e.g. "float_value" in the above code) to my functions. Is my code correct? It is giving errors at runtime when I called session.run.

Answer (score 2):

i solved this by:

```
def np_function_generator(float_value):
    def np_function(np_array1):
         np_array2 = ...
         ... you can use float_value here ...  
         return np_array2
    return np_function


#tensorflow customised op
def tf_function( tf_tensor_in_gpu, float_value):
       np_function = np_function_generator(float_value):
       return  \
       tf.py_func(np_function,[tf_tensor_in_gpu],[tf.float32])
```